# Error saving an edit in a custom component `table_users` was not locked with LOCK TABLES

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, custom-component, database, jtable

I'm getting an error when trying to save edits in my custom component.

I have another edit.php that works well.

I identified that the problem lies in the table file, specifically in the function `check()`.

When I have the function in my table file, whenever I save the edit, it gives me an SQL error:

> `table_users` was not locked with LOCK TABLES

When I take the function out, it gives me a different error (the weirdest part is that even with the function not being there, it still says the function name):

> Error Save failed with the following error:
>   Invalid `parent_id` [0] in PrefixNameTableTableName::check()

The problem is that I don't need `parent_id`. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution:

1 . Verify your table file (make sure the table and the class name is correct).

2 . Make sure your class (in table file) extends JTable and not JTableNested if you don't need parent_id.

3 . Verify all of your class and table names.

4 . Make sure your database user has permissions.

5. You can also uninstall and reinstall your component (don't forget to fix the database before reinstalling it)

You can fix the database by going to

> Extensions > Manage > Database

then click on "Fix"